# how many parent nodes can an XML doc have?

Tags: xml

Is it possible to have more than one set of parent nodes?

example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<parentOne>
    <child>
          <subChild></subChild>
     </child>
</parentOne>
<parentTwo>
    <child>
          <subChild></subChild>
     </child>
</parentTwo>
```

is there a way for that work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Every XML document has [exactly one root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) as per [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed).

> [Definition: There is exactly one element, called the root, or document element, no part of which appears in the content of any other element.] For all other elements, if the start-tag is in the content of another element, the end-tag is in the content of the same element. More simply stated, the elements, delimited by start- and end-tags, nest properly within each other.

Use something like this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<parents>
    <parent id="One">
        <child>
              <subChild></subChild>
         </child>
    </parent>
    <parent id="Two">
        <child>
              <subChild></subChild>
         </child>
    </parent>
</parents>
```

Comment: I thought so, I was just wondering if I could better organize my xml tags. Thank you

Comment: Of course, the link won't work today because of Wikipedia's SOPA blackout.

Comment: Long answer... no... but you should just wrap everything in `<root></root>` and you've got the same thing! :)

Comment: A better link might be to the *Annotated XML Specification*: http://www.xml.com/axml/target.html#sec-well-formed

Comment: yeah, i got the hang of it thank you for your clarification Tim, Thomas, and Richard =)

Answer (score 0):

No, there can only be one parent node (if by that, you mean, having multiple ,  etc). I would have root node of something like , then  etc.

Hope this helps.